# ((System.Object)p == null)

Tags: c#, class, struct, equals

Why do this:

```
    // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
    TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
    if ((System.Object)p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Instead of this:

```
    // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
    TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
    if (p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

I don't understand why you'd ever write ((System.Object)p)?

Regards,

Dan

Comment: I'm waiting for him to say this is how his teacher said to do it or something :)

Comment: Okay but...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Earlz, no. I'm double checking.

Comment: That's interesting, why would they give examples like that on MSDN?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cast to `object` when you don't know or can't be sure whether the original class has overridden `operator ==`:

```
using System;
class AlwaysEqual
{
    public static bool operator ==(AlwaysEqual a, AlwaysEqual b)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(AlwaysEqual a, AlwaysEqual b)
    {
        return true;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object o = new AlwaysEqual();
        AlwaysEqual ae = o as AlwaysEqual;

        if (ae == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ae is null");
        }

        if ((object)ae == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("(object)ae is null");
        }
    }
}
```

This code outputs *only* `"ae is null"`, which is obviously not the case.  The cast to `object` avoids the `AlwaysEqual` class's `operator ==` and is therefore a true reference check against `null`.

Comment: So, casting to ( System.Object ) would force the invocation of "==" in Object? Strange..

Comment: I always prefer the `object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)` syntax in these situations. It spells out the intention of the code much more clearly.

Comment: I'm being dragged away; but I'd love to ask/ research the question (try and rephrase shortly) "when an expert corrects the msdn text should they elaborate more?". Now, that's loaded but I gotta go...

Comment: Note: since c# 7 you can use the "is" Operator to check for null. "is" uses a direct reference comparison. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676426/what-is-the-difference-between-x-is-null-and-x-null

Answer (score 1):

Plainly speaking, It's pointless. Null can always be assigned(except for non-nullables such as ints and structs) regardless of type so it can always be checked for. The cast is not necessary

If `TwoDPoint` is a non-nullable type such as a struct then indeed it may have a point. The `(System.Object)` cache would effectively box the struct into a nullable object. But if that was the case then `obj as TwoDPoint` would not be valid. You would need `obj as TwoDPoint?` to make it nullable. (can't use as with non-nullables)

Comment: Hmm okay. Perhaps that's the point, the non-nullables that is. I'll look at it a bit more, thanks. If you have the time - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx
Regards,
Dan

Comment: @Daniel see my edit for why it isn't a non-nullable problem. As for your link though. That is quite curious the overloading of the `==` operator. but the `Equals` function isn't static so if it isn't pointing at a valid object then what happens? That is the correct question :)

Answer (score 1):

Every object in .NET is derived from System.Object so there is no need for explicit cast.

Comment: Cool - yes, took me a while; you're right, I see. Thanks. The msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx confused me. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

And even more concise would be:

```
if (!(obj is TwoDPoint)) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It would also be more efficient if you're just checking that `p` is of the right type.

Answer (score 1):

It makes total sense if that code is inside `Object.Equals` override and you don't want to invoke the equality operator (which might, for example, erroneously call `Equals`). Casting to object allows to call standard equality operator, which compares references.

Normally, you would use `Object.ReferenceEquals` to compare an instance of an object to `null` inside `Equals` override.

For example, this would cause a stack overflow:

```
public class Point {
  public override bool Equals (object other) {
    var otherPoint = other as Point;

    if (other == null)
      return false;

    //...
  }

  public static bool operator == (Point l, Point r) {
    //...
    //null checks
    if (!l.Equals(r))
      return false;
  }
}
```

In the above example equality operator calls `Equals` and because `otherPoint` variable is of type `Point`, it would invoke the equality operator, causing infinite recursion.

Normally, when you override `Equals` and define the equality operator, you would put the comparison logic in the operator and invoke that from the `Equals` override. Bear in mind that it's recommended for the class to be immutable if both are overridden.

```
public class Point {
  public override bool Equals (object other) {
    var otherPoint = other as Point;
    return this == otherPoint;
  }

  //must override GetHashCode() as well

  public static bool operator == (Point l, Point r) {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(l, null) && Object.ReferenceEquals(r, null))
      return true;
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(l, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(r, null))
      return false;
    //actual equality checks
  }
  public static bool operator != (Point l, Point r) {
    return !(l==r);
  }
}
```