# What is the difference between "x is null" and "x == null"?

Tags: c#, .net, null, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

In C# 7, we can use

```
if (x is null) return;
```

instead of

```
if (x == null) return;
```

Are there any advantages to using the new way (former example) over the old way?

Are the semantics any different?

Is it just a matter of taste? If not, when should I use one over the other?

Reference: [What’s New in C# 7.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

Answer (score 459, accepted):

**Update:** The Roslyn compiler has been updated to make the behavior of the two operators the same *when there is no overloaded equality operator*. Please see the [code in the current compiler results](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:%3Eilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmAge06JgFkAjAApOBAFapSyGAA8AlDAC8APlkwwdCMCJEcASC49+AJhHjJ0+UtUylimFp04AvkA==) (`M1` and `M2` in the code) that shows what happens when there is no overloaded equality comparer. They both now have the better-performing `==` behavior. If there is an overloaded equality comparer, [the code still differs](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgqcBmIgJgIGECBvKgrg4Ae14wEAssQAUrAB4BKAgF4AfAQkE0UAgDsArhgwVKASD4DhDcUpkKlc2Ru27O3B1zTqYSvdyL1mol2+lsMAAWqgB0ErISpAC+Tl5ExABsPPyCvAAOiBAwvAiyNma8xEgsBLwMFopF4dZlDOEe3HQJyUZpmQjZuQCEBaxFJf0VltXKvXUNcc28AG6ICGgAJnApxgCiAI6aEBhQorzAAFZwAMZu5ZUEouJSFzX57lP0s/NLK34EAOJwMAAS0EFmLxlqJLhJQt8/gCgSCpHpokA==).

See for older versions of the Roslyn compiler the below analysis.

---

For `null` there isn't a difference with what we are used to with C# 6. However, things become interesting when you change `null` to another constant.

Take this for example:

```
Test(1);

public void Test(object o)
{
    if (o is 1) Console.WriteLine("a");
    else Console.WriteLine("b");
}
```

The test yields `a`. If you compare that to `o == (object)1` what you would have written normally, it does make a lot of difference. `is` takes into consideration the type on the other side of the comparison. That is cool!

I think the `== null` vs. `is null` constant pattern is just something that is very familiar 'by accident', where the syntax of the `is` operator and the equals operator yield the same result.

---

As [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) commented, [`is null` calls `System.Object::Equals(object, object)` where `==` calls `ceq`](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:%3Eilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmAge06JgFkAjAApOBAFapSyGAA8AlDAC8APlkwwdCMCJEcASC49+AJhHjJ0+UtUylimFp04AvkA==).

*IL for `is`:*

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1              // Load argument 1 onto the stack
IL_0001: ldnull               // Push a null reference on the stack
IL_0002: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object) // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
IL_0007: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
```

*IL for `==`:*

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1              // Load argument 1 onto the stack
IL_0001: ldnull               // Push a null reference on the stack
IL_0002: ceq                  // Push 1 (of type int32) if value1 equals value2, else push 0
IL_0004: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
```

Since we are talking about `null`, there is no difference since this [only makes a difference on instances](http://ideone.com/VKZDCe). This could change when you have overloaded the equality operator.

Comment: Yes, that is what i also understand of this new feature. I think it would be mainly useful in `switch` structures, that where a bit limited in c#. But as of `null` is refered, i think it would be just the same using one way or the other..

Comment: I guess so. I don't know the implications on the generated CIL, but I guess it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @PatrickHofman [It looks like `is` calls `object.Equals(x, null)`, while `==` compiles as `ceq`.](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:%3Eilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmAge06JgFkAjAApOBAFapSyGAA8AlDAC8APlkwwdCMCJEcASC49+AJhHjJ0+UtUylimFp04AvkA==) But the result should be the same, as you said.

Comment: As written in the docs:
1) If expr and constant are integral types, the C# equality operator determines whether the expression returns true (that is, whether expr == constant)
2) Otherwise, the value of the expression is determined by a call to the static Object.Equals(expr, constant) method. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is

Comment: @svick it will call `op_Equality` if that's defined on the type in question, which can make a difference in some cases, though a case where behaviour is different with null would be pretty specialised (though not unheard of). This can also make one more performant than the other, though in such cases using `==` along with a cast as per `(object)x == null` is the one that would be lightest in cases where the others had the same behaviour but more work getting there.

Comment: Always beware in mind that `==` is an overloadable operator. You can have any behaviour you want with it. For e.g. this [weirdly implemented `==`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QTpdpT) wont tell you if your instance is truly null. `is null` on other hand will always return true for true null references :) Also, if you have `ReferenceEquals` in your code, VS 2017 light bulbs will suggest to change to `is null`, not `== null` (correctly).

Comment: @PatrickHofman should not IL's be the other way around? == calls System.Object::Equals(object, object) and  is null calls ceq

Comment: Downvoted for complicating the sample code by boxing a value type. Once you box a value, reference comparisons are rarely useful.

Comment: As of C# 9.0 "is not" has been introduced and you can use if (obj is not null) instead of if (!(obj is null)) which ignores the use of !=

Answer (score 157):

#### Overloaded equals operator

There is in fact a difference in semantics between the two comparisons when you are comparing `null` with a type that has overloaded the `==` operator. `foo is null` will use direct reference comparison to determine the result, whereas `foo == null` will of course run the overloaded `==` operator if it exists.

In this example I have introduced a "bug" in the overloaded `==` operator, causing it to always throw an exception if the second argument is `null`:

```
void Main()
{
    Foo foo = null;
    
    if (foo is null) Console.WriteLine("foo is null"); // This condition is met
    if (foo == null) Console.WriteLine("foo == null"); // This will throw an exception
}

public class Foo
{
    public static bool operator ==(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
    {
        if (object.Equals(foo2, null)) throw new Exception("oops");
        return object.Equals(foo1, foo2);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

The IL code for `foo is null` uses the `ceq` instruction to perform a direct reference comparison:

```
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_0004:  ldnull      
IL_0005:  ceq
```

The IL code for `foo == null` uses a call to the overloaded operator:

```
IL_0016:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_0017:  ldnull      
IL_0018:  call        UserQuery+Foo.op_Equality
```

So the difference is, that if you use `==` you risk running user code (which can potentially have unexpected behavior or performance problems).

You can also see how the `Main` method is transformed by the C# compiler, using the [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgASy3A7Mgb2QxKwBYMBZAQwEsA7ACgEpjSilSuMAxAez4YAZgIwBeDPQCuAGxkBuNtwxLutIRkYjBtAM6TZM5jgCcjAETaMeg3PPN5GAPROMAFQAWNgMZ96wWgAXWj9rfQBbAFNA1S51TSsxCWk5Yyg4M0tRJNsZe0cXdy99AHdaOQxAjwAnPhKManoMSIAPb0iAB2C/VQBfZFV0LBheAVUOZRIh9IA2DAAjARkMPg7I6upAvmrxMUZ+QW04ABpRw4EYVk5Jicm4jUY+eYArSO9AgDoAUQBHKWoZLotBdTikjMYqrV6vRIvUvm1Ot0mOYBB1dPlYpMoLgVi83p9fv9AcC+CdhBcHJiSP1rsoqVhMLMFksVmsNlsdgBCPYHcmk0687SXcQAPkqNTqklhGAAcnxAgBlKQdDrbQKRYDw9pdEJMSm0jA0mnIIA=) online tool:

```
private void Main()
{
    Foo foo = null;
    if ((object)foo == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo is null");
    }
    if (foo == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo == null");
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition, note (x is null) requires a class constraint if x is a generic type, while (x == null) and object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) do not.

Comment: And it should also be noted that null coalescing operator (??) and null coalescing assignment operator (??=) like "is" ignores overloaded equals operator (==) too.

Comment: That's very useful answer, that explains why my unit test keep failing.

Comment: The last point doesn't seem to be valid anymore... it fails if -specifically- setting a value type on the constraint (`bool IsNull<T>(T item) where T : struct => item is null; `), but `bool IsNull<T>(T item) => item is null; ` seems to be fine currently

Comment: Thanks @Jcl, I have removed that part from the answer.

Answer (score 44):

There is also a difference when you try to compare a non-null variable to a null value. When using `==`, the compiler will issue a Warning, while when using `is`, the compiler will issue an Error. Most likely, 99% of the time, you want the compiler to shout at you for such a basic mistake. +1 for `is null`.

[image]

[image]

P.S. Tested on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ with NetCore3.1

Comment: This just comes down to your visual studio settings. You can easily tell the compiler to make those warnings into compile errors.

Comment: @BenjaminSutas Indeed you can configure VS to change de default behavior. But the default behavior is generally the one that is expected by most users.