# What is a difference between "foo is null" and "foo == null"

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Is there any difference between: 
`foo is null` and `foo == null`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "x is null" and "x == null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676426/what-is-the-difference-between-x-is-null-and-x-null)

Answer (score 16):

Short version: For well-behaved types, there is no difference between `foo is null` and `foo == null`.

Long version:

When you write `foo == null` and an appropriate overload of `operator ==` exists, then that's what is called. Otherwise, reference equality is used for reference types and value equality is used for value types.

When you write `foo is null` for a reference type, this is compiled as if you wrote `object.Equals(null, foo)` (notice the switched order, it makes a difference). In effect, this performs reference equality comparison between `foo` and `null`. For a value type, `foo is null` does not compile.

This means that if you write a class with `operator ==` that says that some instance of `foo` is equal to `null`, then `foo == null` will give different result than `foo is null`.

An example showing this:

```
using System;

public class Foo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(foo == null);
        Console.WriteLine(foo is null);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) => true;
    // operator != has to exist to appease the compiler
    public static bool operator !=(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) => false;
}
```

This code outputs:

```
True
False
```

When you overload `operator ==`, you should make it behave in a reasonable way, which, among other things, means you should not say that `foo == null` is `true` for non-`null` `foo`. As a side effect of this, under normal circumstances, `foo == null` and `foo is null` will have the same value.

Answer (score 6):

From the MSDN Docs:

**[Is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)**
Checks if an object is compatible with a given type, or (starting with C# 7) tests an expression against a pattern. The is keyword evaluates type compatibility at runtime. It determines whether an object instance or the result of an expression can be converted to a specified type.

**[== is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator)**
For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the strings.

Summary: No, there isn't in this example. `is` is normally use if you wanna check the `type`. In this case it is null. `==` if you wanna check the value. In this case also null, so both would evaluate to true.

Comment: That documentation is confusing. `==` can be overloaded, so, for user-defined types, it can return whatever you want.