# Is it okay to check for null with 'is' keyword?

Tags: c#, null

In a code review that I have made today to one of my team mates, I have seen him checking properties for null with the `is` keyword, like:

```
if(myVariable is null)
{
    //do something
}
```

I was tempted to disagree of this type of checking, but I don't feel so confident on my knowledge about it. Is it really okay to check for null like this?

Comment: What is the type of the property?

Comment: @EnterTheCode it has many different types as it is used in a lot of places in the code, but I can assure you that it is a reference type which is valid to be checked for null.

Comment: Well I didnt even know that would compile - always use this `object.ReferenceEquals(null, myVariable)` - not entirely sure why but someone once told me "use that"

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/30/what-the-meaning-of-is-is/

Comment: `if(myVariable is null)` is compiling ?

Comment: I had Resharper recently suggest changing a call to `ReferenceEquals` to `is null` instead.

Comment: @meJustAndrew The following question seems to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607581/what-is-a-difference-between-foo-is-null-and-foo-null.

Comment: @ckuri, I just want to add that `is null` will compile only if you have a reference type, but `ReferenceEquals(null, x)` always compiles no matter to what type your objects have.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: It is a new feature for C# 7. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/ for the details.

Comment: @meJustAndrew: Just to clarify: the fact that `is null` fails at compile time when `x` is not a reference type is a *feature*.  `ReferenceEquals(null, x)` for non-reference-type `x` is almost always an error. If `x` is a nullable value type then use `!x.HasValue`, or `x == null)`; if `x` is a non-nullable value type then it will always be false.  Either way, it is a mistake, and so it should be caught at compile time.

Comment: Indeed @EricLippert , I knew this is a feature and I am happy because it was built this way, because it can be confusing in the case of `ReferenceEquals(value, value)` people would be tempted to think that the result of this will always be true (as Resharper is suggesting) while in fact it is actually false for value types.