# Obj is null vs object.ReferenceEquals(Obj, null)

Tags: c#

What is the difference between

```
if (Obj is null) Console.WriteLine("Value is null");

if (object.ReferenceEquals(Obj, null)) Console.WriteLine("Value is null");
```

I am trying to override the `==` operator and as such cannot use `Obj == null`.

Comment: Since `object.ReferenceEquals()` internally is `==` check ([ReferenceEquals](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,4d607d6d56a93c7e,references)), then: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "x is null" and "x == null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676426/what-is-the-difference-between-x-is-null-and-x-null)

Answer (score 0):

`ReferenceEquals(obj, null)` and `(obj is null)` do exactly the same thing, but the latter is only available as part of C# 7.0 syntax and later.

Comment: I don't know who is down-voting this but IIRC, this is exactly right!

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6856