# Should I use == or 'is' to check for null in C# 7?

Tags: null, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

from the C# 7 we have available `is` pattern matching operator. I would like to ask if it is recommended to use `is` operator rather than `==` to check for `null`. Is there any difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "x is null" and "x == null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676426/what-is-the-difference-between-x-is-null-and-x-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` can be customized on your type, so `x == null` may not be just the intended null check.

For a null check, you could do `x is null`, `(object)x == null` or `object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)`.