# Why does the C# 'is' operator give a correct result when comparing two boolean values and should I use it?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Id noticed that this `is` operator produces the same results and even compiles the same (see [this gist](https://sharplab.io/#gist:86af8c934199981ac80c5ecb808446ea)) as the `==` operator. Is this a correct usage of the `is` operator given that I can only see things related to runtime type-testing in the docs?

```cs
bool test = false;

if(!test)
{
// some code
}

//OR

if(test is false)
{
// some code
}
```

Comment: Beacuse you can use the `is` variable to compare a variable's value to a _literal_. And I would suggest not using it in this way.

Comment: See the doc [is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is)

Comment: This isn't a correct usage of *either* operator in this case, in my not so humble opinion. Use `if (!test)`, they're booleans for a reason.

Comment: [This covers it a little bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40676671/3181933)

Comment: @JeroenMostert that is a fair point. I wouldn't use that in a real scenario so it's a mystery as to why I've decided to represent it like that now :facepalm:.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, it's completely valid - it's a [*constant pattern*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#constant-pattern). In that sense, it's "correct". It's not an implementation detail or bug on the part of the compiler.

It's fairly unconventional to use it this way within an `if` statement though - constant patterns are more commonly used in switch statements or expressions.

They're not *completely* equivalent though. Pattern matching with `is` doesn't perform custom conversions on the left-hand side of the `is` operator. So take this example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

struct MyBool
{
    public bool Value { get;}
    
    public MyBool(bool value) => Value = value;
    
    public static implicit operator bool(MyBool value) => value;
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyBool x = new MyBool(true);
        // Valid: uses the implicit conversion from MyBool to bool
        Console.WriteLine(x == true);
        // Invalid
        Console.WriteLine(x is true);
    }
}
```

The error message for the last statement is perhaps a little confusing:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'MyBool'

That's due to this part of the [constant pattern behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#constant-pattern):

> When the input value is not an open type, the constant expression is implicitly converted to the type of the matched expression; if the type of the input value is not pattern-compatible with the type of the constant expression, the pattern-matching operation is an error.

Interestingly, if you add a conversion from `bool` to `MyBool`, the error changes:

> error CS0150: A constant value is expected

But fundamentally it's not valid, anyway.

Comment: It doesn't even compile when adding true/false operators to MyBool. TIL.

Comment: (Trivially), another difference is that `MyBool` could also declare its own `==` operator, which `x == true` will call, but `is` will not. :)

Comment: @Sweeper: Will add that in, yes.

Comment: @Sweeper: Actually, I won't because it's slightly tricky to describe exactly what notional of equality it uses, given string comparisons. Will leave as-is...

Answer (score 0):

It is valid, because it is part of pattern matching feature. But as @Jon Skeet already answered, it is not conventional to use it to check equality with bool variables.
In C# 9, it's common use case is checking multiple conditions at once, like

```
int x = Random.Next(50);
if (x is >5 and <17)
//do something
```

It's syntactic sugar mostly though.