# Why in Visual Studio 2022 "Object != null" does not work but "Object is not null" works?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I am developing an application in .NET Core 7.0. See the code block below shows the condition that works and the one that doesn't.

Please suggest why is it happening?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Here is the code snippet.

```
        User dbUser = databaseUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == user.ObjectGuid).Value;
        if (dbUser != null)
        {
            // Handle user when it' null
        }
```

The databaseUsers is a SortedDictionary<string, User>. When the dbUser null it still go inside the if condition and only behave correctly when i change the condition to "dbUser is not null".

Comment: Hi, could you provide more details? What does it mean 'doesn't work'?

Comment: Visual Studio is just the editor, not the language. `user != null` works just fine. Post actual code (not images) that reproduce the problem. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled.

Comment: Could you please include example code (as text within the question) that demonstrates the issue. Please also explain what doesn't work.

Comment: My quess?: `User` has an operator overload that doesn't handle null correctly. Using pattern matching does not call operators declared in that class.

Comment: If what you claim was true hundreds of thousands of developers would notice because **all** C# programs would break. Something strange is going on either with `User` or `GetByIdAsync`

Comment: Please check if this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676426/what-is-the-difference-between-x-is-null-and-x-null

Answer (score 4):

Please provide more info.

The difference between `!=` and `is not null` is that `!=` can be overridden.

That means that you can change is behavior.  As you can see [in these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Your `!=` has probably been overridden in `User` class